# R module for creating plots of prototypical individuals from fitted models?

Tags: r, regression, data-visualization, interaction

In order to help interpret fitted models — especially those with interaction terms and non-linear components — I've found it useful to plot predicted values of a dependent variables for what we might think of as *prototypical individuals*. I would like to know if there are existing R modules that help do this.

The idea behind these plots of prototypical individuals is to use parameter estimates from a model to plot the predicted values of some dependent variable across a range of an independent variables (often the x-asis is time in the context of longitudinal models) for different values of a (usually categorical) variable while holding everything at the sample mean or median.

This is a technique discussed in depth by Judith Singer and John Willett in their book on [Applied Longitudinal Data Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0195152964) (see slide 20 in [this presentation (PPT)](http://www.gse.harvard.edu/~faculty/singer/Presentations/ALDA%20Chapter%204.ppt) by the authors) Another example might be [this figure (Figure 2)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2843144/figure/F2/) from [this paper (PubMedCentral)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2843144/) on development trajectories or [this plot (PNG)](http://mako.cc/copyrighteous/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/abs2013_protoplot.png) from [a recent paper of my own](http://mako.cc/copyrighteous/the-remixing-dilemma).

I have written R code that takes a series of different model objects along with a long list of optional arguments that let you specify a wide variety of options for creating these plots. My module then gives you back a data frame that you can use with [ggplot2](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/) or your plotting software of choice. As I invest more time into my own code, I'm wondering if its worth continuing development of this and the release of a package in CRAN or if there is an existing system I might use and build upon.

The only similar module I know about is [visreg](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/visreg/index.html) which is great but which, as far as I can tell, is designed to visualize the fit of model rather than creating plots of prototypical individuals from fitted models that one might use in publications.

Comment: It seems to me the novelty of your work will lie in how you define "prototypical" (of which I am not aware of anything directly related). It reminds me a bit of [Gelman and Pardoe (2007)](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/ape17.pdf) in which they use Mahalanobis distances to define "average" effect sizes. Those same distances can be used to construct potential "protypical" individuals.

Comment: Thanks Andy! I'm not thinking of this a paper. I've written code already. I'm just wondering if I should release this code into CRAN or if I should contribute to another project that is doing something. Great suggestion about Gelman and Pardoe! I have run into that before I think I should absolutely build that in!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing I've found so far is John Fox's [Effects Package](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v08/i15/paper). The package is both actively maintained and extremely mature — you can read [this 2003 paper about it](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v08/i15/paper) in the [Journal of Statistical Software](http://www.jstatsoft.org). I was able to use it recently to do most of what I had been doing in my own little package. The code to use it is less fragile and more clear.

With the package, you construct a list and set the `xlevels` so that they include a range across your x-axis variable while holding the rest at the values of the prototypical individual(s). The `effect()` function will return an object that contains both predicted values and 95% confidence intervals for a variety of different types of model objects.

The package includes a good deal of plotting code. Although these plots are instructive and useful, they are rather "old-school R" and not publication quality. That said, the `eff` (or `effpoly`) object includes all the data necessary to construct a dataset to render beautifully with [ggplot2](http://ggplot2.org/) or similar.